# Auto-populate dates between list of dates in Google Sheets and link with additional column

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sequence, google-query-language

I have a spreadsheet that lists when an employee requests leave away from the business.

[image: Data feed input]

What formula can I use to produce the below output based on the data fed into the spreadsheet please?

I require:

- Separate rows to be generated to show each individual day that the employee is off for, linked to their name
- The list to include all employees in the list

[image: Desired required output]

This is a [Sample Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cvjQ8TcKjoPkFETQOPNU1YOk6occgLqoyCvzcnGYKf8/edit#gid=0) containing the data I have put together. Unfortunately the only formula I have come across that autopopulates between dates is:

```
=ArrayFormula((TO_DATE(row(indirect("A"&Input!B2):indirect("A"&Input!C2)))))
```

however, this does not also bring across the contents of Column A and does not process numerous rows of data at a time.

Comment: What research and learning have you already done toward solving this problem? What formulas have you already tried? What were the results of those formula attempts? Keep in mind that this is a free, volunteer-run forum designed to share information or to offer "small help" (like tweaking a formula or script someone else has already put time into and nearly gotten correct) as opposed to being a place where people can get customized work done at no cost. (No such place exists.) In addition, please share a link to the sample spreadsheet from which volunteers can work and test.

Comment: I also highly recommend that you do not have the results returned within the same sheet as the source/original data, as that would leave two incongruous data sets side by side, which is bad practice in general.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Erik - I have updated the post with research/learning I have tried already as I am already full aware around the purpose of this site being around support - thank you for the reminder however. I have also added a link to a sample sheet as requested. Yes, the data being side by side was purely to demonstrate the output I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(DAYS(C2:C10, B2:B10)+1>=
 SEQUENCE(1, MAX(DAYS(C2:C10, B2:B10))), A2:A10&"×"&B2:B10+
 SEQUENCE(1, MAX(DAYS(C2:C10, B2:B10)), 0), )), "×"), "where Col2>0", ))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is with `sequence()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    split( 
      flatten( 
        if( 
          ( D2:D <= sequence( 1, max(D2:E) - min(D2:E) + 1, min(D2:E) ) )
          *
          ( E2:E >= sequence( 1, max(D2:E) - min(D2:E) + 1, min(D2:E) ) ), 
          A2:A & "→" & trim( to_date( sequence( 1, max(D2:E) - min(D2:E) + 1, min(D2:E) ) ) ), 
          iferror(1/0) 
        ) 
      ), 
      "→", false, true 
    ), 
    "where Col2 is not null", 0 
  ) 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FILTER(A2:A&"~"&IF((B2:B+SEQUENCE(1,60))>C2:C,,B2:B+SEQUENCE(1,60)),A2:A<>"")),"~",1,0),"Select * WHERE Col2 Is Not Null"),{"",""}))`

This will handle up to 60 days off at a time. You can just set the two instances of `60` to your maximum number of contiguous days off per person.